# how to write navigation drawer with activities in android(with out using fragments)?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement navigation drawer with activities. I was followed [this](http://androiddeveloperdemo.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-navigation-drawer-with-multiple.html) tutorial, but its not navigation other activities(xml) it's taking base activity xml only but I need to navigation their own xml activities.

```
public class Item1Activity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         *  We will not use setContentView in this activty 
         *  Rather than we will use layout inflater to add view in FrameLayout of our base activity layout*/

        /**
         * Adding our layout to parent class frame layout.
         */
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout. activity_main, frameLayout);
        /**
         * Setting title and itemChecked  
         */
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(listArray[position]);          
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
    }
}
```

It's only inflating base activity xml file.